# Input data must have class mids

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I'm working on a school project where I need to impute missing data and after the imputation with mice I'm trying to produce completed data sets with the complete-function.

When I run them one by one everything works fine, but I'd like to use a for-loop in case I want to have more than just `m = 5` imputations. Now, when trying to run the `for-loop`, I always get the error

> Error in complete(imputation[1]) : Input data must have class 'mids'.

However when I look up the class it **is** mids, what's going wrong here?

This is my code:

```
imputation <- mice(data = data, m = 5, method = "norm", maxit = 1, seed = 500) 
m <- 5
for(i in 1:m){
  completeData[m] <- complete(imputation[m])
  print(summary(completeData[m]))
}
```

Could someone maybe help me out here?

Comment: Please tell me in your real application you don't use `maxit=1`

Comment: my teacher said it's okay to do so? but should I re-consider this, is it possible that this could lead to errors?

Comment: It won't lead to errors per say. It may just give you really shitty imputations. The chained equation algorithm should run to convergence. You're only allowing it to run a single iteration. The imputation results are probably therefore pretty worthless.

Comment: tbh I was wondering about this as well, I'm not quite sure why he proposed this solution, he also suggested norm as method, however my variable with the NAs is categorial and norm imputes odd values but I need even ones, so I'm considering using cart instead...

Comment: If all of your data is categorical, I strongly recommend package `imputeMulti`. I'm biased as the package author; but my tests show that it's much more accurate than any of `Amelia`, `mice`, or `Hmisc`. And this result is robust to the amount of missingness in the data... note that `imputeMulti` is ONLY for categorical data, which does not include mixed (categorical and continuous) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are getting error because the class is not `mids`:

```
imputation[1]
# $call
# mice(data = walking, m = 5, maxit = 0, seed = 500)

class(imputation[1])
# [1] "list"
```

From the manual for `?complete`:

> Usage
>
> `complete(x, action = 1, include = FALSE)`

```
library(mice)

# dummy data imputation
data(walking)
imputation <- mice(walking, max = 0, m = 5, seed = 500)

# using for loop
m <- 5
for(i in 1:m){
  completeData <- complete(imputation, m)
  print(summary(completeData))
}

# I prefer to use lapply
lapply(seq(imputation$m), function(i) summary(complete(imputation, i)))
```